# Java Applet and dll

Tags: java, dll, applet, twain

I'm writing a web application that allows users to upload documents importing them directly from devices (i.e. scanners).

I would like to realize a simple web app that uses a Java Applet to handle device communication. I have created the jtwain.dll following this tutorial :
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/11/18/twain.html
and a demo app works fine in standalone mode.

Now I need to switch to applet but I don't know how to distribute the jtwain.dll to the client  in order to make the applet work fine (this app will be used in an intranet where the clients are Windows XP or later).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this a long time ago, but the gist of it is that you want to extract the DLL out of your applet's code base so you'll store it in the JAR, and then you want to copy it into the /lib/ext folder of the JRE.

```
 //Where this is an applet
 URL codeBase= this.getCodeBase();
 URL twainUrl new URL(codeBase, "jtwain.dll");
 String javaHome=System.getProperty("java.home");
 //copy the contents of twainUrl to javaHome\lib\ext
```

You'll need your applet to be signed.

Comment: Thank you Mike. And then, once I copied the content of twain.dll in /lib/ext, can I load library using System.loadLibrary("jtwain") or I need to use System.load(FULL/PATH/TO/JTWAIN.DLL)?

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.6.0_10, applets can be (embedded &) launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS not only makes it easier to deploy natives, but can also partition the download by OS (`.so` for *nix, `.dll` for Windows etc.).

Of course, the same could be done from an application launched using JWS.  A free floating frame (or applet) is always easier to get working and deployed than an embedded applet.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can include your dll into JAR file and load it dynamically